# Apache Curator ZooKeeper - KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for, error

Tags: maven, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I use following Apache Curator Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-x-async</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Locally, I have started `zookeeper-3.4.13` server

I try to create `EPHEMERAL` ZNode with the following code:

```
    int sleepMsBetweenRetries = 100;
    int maxRetries = 3;
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryNTimes(maxRetries, sleepMsBetweenRetries);

    CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("127.0.0.1:2181", retryPolicy);

    client.start();

    String taskPathZombie = "/tasks/b5957aa6-e250-41e0-a39b-521da61ca937";

    client.create().withMode(CreateMode.EPHEMERAL).forPath(taskPathZombie);
```

but it fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException: KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /tasks/b5957aa6-e250-41e0-a39b-521da61ca937
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:103) ~[zookeeper-3.5.3-beta.jar:3.5.3-beta-8ce24f9e675cbefffb8f21a47e06b42864475a60]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[zookeeper-3.5.3-beta.jar:3.5.3-beta-8ce24f9e675cbefffb8f21a47e06b42864475a60]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:1525) ~[zookeeper-3.5.3-beta.jar:3.5.3-beta-8ce24f9e675cbefffb8f21a47e06b42864475a60]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1181) ~[curator-framework-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1158) ~[curator-framework-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callWithRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:64) ~[curator-client-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:100) ~[curator-client-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1155) ~[curator-framework-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:605) ~[curator-framework-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:595) ~[curator-framework-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:573) ~[curator-framework-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:49) ~[curator-framework-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the incorrect combination of Apache Curator and ZooKeeper. Right now the combination of `Apache Curator 4.0.1` and `ZooKeeper 3.5.4-beta` works fine

Answer (score 8):

If Zookeeper Server version is 3.4.x then following works fine.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>
```

However, to use Zookeeper 3.5.x as client (for newer features like node container) along with Curator 4.x, run server 3.5.x version otherwise client throws **UnimplementedException**